# Main class run with exception in thread error with JUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm using the crimson editor along with the command prompt console for compiling and running the programs. I've just installed and am new to JUnit. Currently, I'm following a basic tutorial from TutorialsPoint.com and have followed the steps setting the classpath.

The link to the tutorial is available here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm

From this tutorial, there's an ending part whereby you will asked to create class files to test the JUnit. Eventually, after compiling, I tried to run the main class but I was presented with a long series of errors so I was hoping you guys can help me out here.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestJunit {
   @Test
   public void testAdd() {
      String str= "Junit is working fine";
      assertEquals("Junit is working fine",str);
   }
}
```

Main class:

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }
      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

And the screenshot of the console displaying the error:

[image]

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how Hamcrest is coming into the picture; I suspect a CLASSPATH issue. Questions: Where did you place the downloaded junit-4.10.jar from Step 3? Did you set JUNIT_HOME from Step 4? If yes, to what? Did you set CLASSPATH from Step 5? If yes, to what? Thanks. :)

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald hey hi there! I placed the downloaded .jar file in C:\JUnit and I set my JUNIT_HOME to point to its folder. As for my classpath I have this: %CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.12.jar;.;

thanks!

Comment: Hello. :) I have a few ideas. First, the tutorial uses junit-4.10.jar - retry with that? %CLASSPATH% shouldn't be a part of your classpath. Could you post the CLASSPATH= line from the output of 'set' in a command prompt window? Thanks. Also, the trailing semicolon in your classpath is probably unnecessary and possibly harmful. (Would check more locally, but am replying from a phone at present.)

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald hi Mark thanks for getting back to the question. Erm I think I only manually set up a new system variable for CLASSPATH as `%CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.12.jar;.;%HAMCREST_HOME%\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;.;`

oh ok sure I will change it to `%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.12.jar;%HAMCREST_HOME%\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;` do you think it will be better? thanks again pal.

Sorry for the confusion sometimes I also not sure what I'm actually doing I'm still a very amateur computing person. ;)

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald hi again mate! yup I got it working now thanks so much for your help. the actual problem lies with the classpath value. cheers!

Comment: Excellent - glad to hear it. What was the CLASSPATH that worked for you? We should post it as an answer in order to close out this question.

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald oh I see ok sure I update the question now erm can I ask you another question? why do we have to bring in the hamcrest thingy when the whole thing is about junit? I'm confused lol.

Comment: I also find the Hamcrest need mysterious, as the code does not refer to it. I plan to investigate this myself when next at computer. Did you modify the sample tutorial code? Maybe try with junit-4.10.jar and no hamcrest? I was not able to reproduce your issue when using junit-4.10.jar as recmmended in the linked tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add hamcrest-core-1.3.jar to your classpath.
Download the jar from Hamcrest site: https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/

Assert class of JUnit need Hamcrest matchers.

Comment: hi pz74 I have that as well for my classpath but not sure whether my input is correct. I have it as %CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.12.jar;.;%HAMCREST_HOME%\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;.;

I installed it because it was provided as a link as well on the website at https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem with the help of Mark A.Fitzgerald and pz74 is that my `CLASSPATH` value was setted wrongly. I have amended it to `C:\JUnit\junit-4.12.jar;C:\HAMCREST\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;` and hamcrest had to be installed as well.